# Number of occurrences in a string, unexpected white space

Tags: java, arrays

I am failing the test case that my professor gave us. It's saying that my code has an extra white space in it but I can't find where it is at.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sequence {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type text: ");
    String str = scan.nextLine();

    int[] count = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    {
        char ch = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)); 

        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') 
        { 
            count[ch - 'a']++; 
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.printf("%c=%d ", 'a' + i, count[i]);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: `"%c=%d "` ← Right there, **before the end-quote**! Since the space is unconditional, there will always be a space after the last output, not just between outputs.

Comment: When I remove that space it takes the spaces out of the whole statement so instead of returning "a = 0, b = 0, c = 0 ....." it returns "a=0b=0c=0...."

Comment: So stop the loop one run earlier and make the last print manually..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ways to only print spaces between *entries*:

1. Print the space separately, so it can be conditional:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
       if (i != 0)
           System.out.print(' ');
       System.out.printf("%c=%d", 'a' + i, count[i]);
   }
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
       System.out.printf("%c=%d", 'a' + i, count[i]);
       if (i < count.length - 1)
           System.out.print(' ');
   }
   ```

   I recommend the first one, since the condition is way simpler.
2. Build a string using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) it when done:

   ```
   StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
       buf.append(String.format("%c=%d ", 'a' + i, count[i]));
   }
   System.out.print(buf.toString().trim());
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
       buf.append((char) ('a' + i)).append('=').append(count[i]).append(' ');
   }
   System.out.print(buf.toString().trim());
   ```
3. Build a string using Java 8's [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

   ```
   StringJoiner buf = new StringJoiner(" ");
   for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
       buf.add(String.format("%c=%d", 'a' + i, count[i]));
   }
   System.out.print(buf.toString());
   ```
4. Use Java 8 streams:

   ```
   System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, count.length)
           .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%c=%d", 'a' + i, count[i]))
           .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another way:

```
String concatString = ""; 
String tempString;
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    tempString = String.format("%c=%d", (char)('a' + i), count[i]);
    concatString += concatString.equals("") ? tempString : " " + tempString;
}
System.out.println(concatString);
```

A Ternary Operator is use to add the whitespace when needed.